# Formula in Excel that references another Excel file based on cell reference

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I want to make a formula that references a cell in another excel file.  I have figured that out as below:

```
='C:\Users\17\Desktop\[JAN-11 2011.xlsx]1'!$H$44
```

But as the cell L1 in this worksheet is Data cell set to month so it show current month so I want to be able to do something as below:

```
='C:\Users\17\Desktop\[&L1& 2011.xlsx]1'!$H$44
```

but this is not working. How do I get this function to work off of the cell L1?

Comment: Note to voter for cancellation -  Why? This is a valid question

Comment: Thought this would suit on http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Try using string concatenation like so:

```
='C:\Users\17\Desktop[' & TEXT(L1, "mmm-dd") & ' 2011.xlsx]1'!$H$44
```

Comment: @jaminator, Did you make L1 exactly equal to "JAN-11"?

Comment: @jaminator, based on the information that you disclosed to iDevlop, I've modified my formula to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Lance Roberts suggestion, but include it in a `INDIRECT()` function, like this: `=INDIRECT('C:\Users\17\Desktop[' & L1 & ' 2011.xlsx]1'!$H$44)`

Comment: the L1 cell is a formatted to month type and it exactly has JAN-11 in it