# Excel VBA inserting formula with variable that references a different sheet links to saved file rather than open file

Tags: vba, excel

I have this line in a long sub and as title mentions instead of using values from the open workbook it uses the saved file and every time it runs it requires manual linking to file.
MC is a workbook APs is a workbook name as a string cl is a range.

```
MC.Sheets("MasterC").Range("$Z$1").Value = "='[" & APs & " ]Stock'!" & cl.Offset(0, 11).Address
```

this is a line in a for loop where cl is a single cell in a range.So can't use absolute values. I've used `.formulaR1C1`instead of `.value` to no avail.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716729/help-in-making-formula-in-excel-that-references-another-excel-file-based-on-cell

Comment: The loop is a solver loop and this is the target so changes need to be reflected. This problem is particularly puzzling as have formulas in other cells that reference different workbooks with no issue but those use more absolute values with  only variable being workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured out that it was a trivial thing

`MC.Sheets("MasterC").Range("$Z$1").Value = "='[" & APs & "]Stock'!" & cl.Offset(0, 11).Address`

In original line there was a space between " and the square bracket causing issues. Moral of story check for spaces.